# Need SQL query with good performance to select data that does NOT match criteria

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization

I have a database with

- a `company` table
- a `country` table
- a `company_country` n:n table which defines which company is available in which country
- a `product` table (each product belongs to one specific `categoryId`)
- and a `company_product_country` n:n:n table that defines which company offers which product in which country.

The latter has the three primary key columns `companyId`, `productId`, `countryId` and the additional columns `val` and `limitedAvailability`. `val` is an ENUM with the values `yes|no|n/a`, and `limitedAvailability` is an ENUM with the values `0|1`.
Products within categories 1 or 2 are available in all countries and therefore get `countryId = 0`. But at the same time, only these very products may have a `limitedAvailability = 1`.

An SQLFiddle with a test database can be found here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a065a/1/0
It contains five countries, products and companies.

**Background information on what I need to select from the database:**

A PHP script generates a search form where an arbitrary list of countries and products can be selected. The products are separated by categories (I did not add the category table in the sample database, because it is not needed in this case). For the first category, I can select whether to exclude products with limited availability.

Generating the desired result works fine:
It displays all companies that are available in the selected countries and have *at least one of the selected products available*. The result offers a column that defines how many of the selected products are available by company.
If the user defines that one or more categories should not contain products with limited availability, then the products within the corresponding categories will not count as a match if the company offers them with limited availability only.

I am pleased with the performance of this query. My original database has got around 15 countries, 100 companies and 150 products. Selecting *everything* in the search form occupies the MySQL server for around two seconds which is acceptable for me.

**The problem:**

After generating the result list of companies which matches as many product search criteria as possible, I use PHP to iterate through those companies and run another SQL query that should give me the list of products that the company does *not* offer corresponding to the search criteria. The following is an example query for companyId 1 to find out which products are *not* available when

- the desired products have the `productId`s 2, 4 and 5
- the product's country availability should be at least one of the `countryId`s 1, 2 or 3
- the product should not have a `limitedAvailability` when it is from `categoryId = 2`:

  ```
  SELECT DISTINCT p.name 
  FROM `product` p
  LEFT JOIN `company_product_country` cpc ON `p`.`productId` = `cpc`.`productId` AND `cpc`.`companyId` = 1 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(
          SELECT * 
          FROM company_product_country cpcTmp 
          WHERE `cpcTmp`.`companyId` = 1 
          AND cpcTmp.val = 'yes'
          AND (
                  cpcTmp.limitedAvailability = 0 
                  OR p.categoryId NOT IN(2) 
          ) 
          AND cpcTmp.productId = p.productId
  )
  AND p.`productId` IN (2,4,5) 
  AND countryId IN(0,1,2,3);
  ```

The database along with this query can be found on the SQLFiddle linked above.

The query generates the correct result, but its performance dramatically decreases with the number of products. My local SQL server needs about 4 seconds per company when searching for 150 products in 15 countries. This is inaccpetable when iterating through 100 companies. Is there any way to improve this query, like avoiding the `IN(...)` function containing up to 150 products? Or should I maybe split the query into two like so:

1. First fetch the unmatched products that do not have country Id 0 and are `IN` the desired `countryId`s
2. Then fetch the unmatched products in `countryId = 0` and if applicable filter `limitedAvailability = 0`

?

Your help is gladly appreciated!

Comment: Your fiddle take 1ms, how long take on your side? And why you need `DISTINCT`?

Comment: Well, the test database has too less content to reproduce the problem, sorry. The fiddle always takes 1ms here, too. The `DISTINCT` is necessary when a product is not offered by the company in many of the desired countries. Otherwise the product is listed multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest writing the query like this:

```
SELECT p.name 
FROM product p
WHERE EXISTS (select 1
              from company_product_country cpc
              where p.productid = cpc.productid and
                    cpc.companyid = 1 and
                    cpc.countryid in (1, 2, 3)
             ) and
      NOT EXISTS (select 1
                  from company_product_country cpcTmp 
                  where cpcTmp.productId = p.productId and
                        cpcTmp.companyId = 1 and
                        cpcTmp.val = 'yes' and
                        cpcTmp.limitedAvailability = 0
                 ) AND
      NOT EXISTS (select 1
                  from company_product_country cpcTmp 
                  where cpcTmp.productId = p.productId and
                        cpcTmp.companyId = 1 and
                        cpcTmp.val = 'yes' and
                        p.categoryId NOT IN (2) 
                 )
      p.`productId` IN (2, 4, 5) ;
```

Then, you want the following indexes:

- `product(productid, categoryid, name)`
- `company_product_country(productid, companyid, countryid)`
- `company_product_country(productid, companyid, val, limitedavailability)`
- `company_product_country(productid, companyid, val, category)`

Note:  these indexes completely "cover" the query, meaning that all columns in the query come from the indexes.  For most purposes, is probably sufficient to have a single index on `company_product_country`.  Any of the three would do.

Comment: I think you forgotten the 'cpc' here: `select 1 from company_product_country ` **cpc** where ...

Comment: That was brilliant, you made my day, Gordon! Needed to tweak the query a bit in order to generate the correct results, but the performance is awesome no matter how long the list of products is now! Also, I'm feeling so stupid that I did not think of adding indexes on the two extra columns although I have these `limitedAvailability = X` and `val = Y` conditions in the query... Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 0):

Take the query that identifies the products that match the user selection. Subquery it and outer join it to the products table. Exclude the matches.
[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a065a/9)

```
SELECT p.name
FROM 
    product p LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT productId 
        FROM company_product_country cpcTmp 
        WHERE companyId = 1 AND 
        countryId IN (0,1,2,3) AND
        (
            productId IN (4, 5) OR 
            (productId = 2 AND limitedAvailability = 0)
        )
    ) t
    ON p.productId = t.productId

WHERE 
    t.productId IS NULL AND 
    p.productId IN (2,4,5)
```

Comment: Your query unfortunately checks `productId = 2` instead of `category = 2` within the JOIN, so this does not work. This might have been more obvious if I had provided a test DB with more content, sorry!

Comment: The inner query doesn't matter. It just needs to be the query you use to identify which products the company has that matches the search criteria. The key point is the outer join exclusion.